# How to compare two different columns of two/more rows

Tags: sql

I need help to query a single table where i need to compare two rows using two different columns.

eg:

```
EMP Table
EmpId EmpName EmpIDNum EmpAddNum
1      xyz        123   456
2      wer        345   123
3      qwe        478   908
4      ghe        123   567
5      fde        456   123
```

Here in the above table, i need to look for the rows which have same ID number(this can be done by using `group by` clause) and I am looking for how to get two rows where one row's EmpIDNum is other row's EmpAddNum.

I need to get these two things using a single query.
Please help.

Comment: Group by two columns... Group by EmpIDNum, EmpAddNum

Comment: I don't see exactly what you mean. Which ID are you talking about in the first condition? What would you want in your result based on the example data?

Comment: show us your desirable result

Comment: Hi Mate,
Group by EmpIDNum, EmpAddNum would look for two rows where those two rows will have same values for both the fields.

Comment: Hi Guffa
my query shud contain rows which satisfies two conditions.1.rows which have same EmpIDNum,2.rows where one row's EMPIDNum is another row's EmpAddNum so my results shud contain EmpId EmpName EmpIDNum EmpAddNum 1 xyz 123 null 4 ghe 123 null 5 fde null 123,as you can see in the first two rows of the results i have displayed null for the field EmpAddNum which indicates these two rows have same EmpIDNum but not EmpAddNum

Answer (score 1):

The key is to create 2 alias for the same table and operate upon it.

```
create table #temp(ID int, num1 int, num2 int)
insert into #temp values (1,123,234)
insert into #temp values (2,234,345)
insert into #temp values (3,345,123)

--query just to create a dummy table fro your reference
--main query starts from here

select * from #temp where ID in
((select t1.id  from #temp t1, #temp t2
where t1.num1 = t2.num2 and t1.num1 = 123),(select t2.id  from #temp t1, #temp t2
where t1.num1 = t2.num2 and t1.num1 = 123))

--sorry for not indenting it
drop table #temp


--returns
--ID    num1   num2
-- 1     123    234
-- 3     345    123
```

The OTHER answer given by me is much better. have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

If you want more than 1 row to mach in the second cloumn then

```
create table #temp(ID int, num1 int, num2 int)

insert into #temp values (1,123,234)
insert into #temp values (2,234,345)
insert into #temp values (3,345,123)
insert into #temp values (4,567,123)


--query just to create a dummy table fro your reference
--main query starts from here

select * from #temp where ID in
(select t1.id  from #temp t1, #temp t2
where t1.num1 = t2.num2 and t1.num1 = 123) or ID in
(select t2.id  from #temp t1, #temp t2
where t1.num1 = t2.num2 and t1.num1 = 123)

--sorry for not indenting it
drop table #temp



--returns
--ID    num1   num2
-- 1     123    234
-- 3     345    123
-- 4     567    123
```

Answer (score 0):

if I correctly understood your question, in SQLSerever2005+ you can try this

```
SELECT t1.EmpID, t1.EmpName, t1.EmpIDNum, t1.EmpAddNum
FROM EMPtbl t1 
  CROSS APPLY(
              SELECT t2.EmpIDNum
              FROM EMPtbl t2
              GROUP BY t2.EmpIDNum              
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
              INTERSECT
              SELECT t3.EmpIDNum
              FROM EMPtbl t3              
              WHERE T1.EmpIDNum IN (t3.EmpAddNum, t3.EmpIDNum)
              ) o
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67125/1/0)